# Create GUID in Azure Data Factory (Derived Columns)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate A GUID with the Expression Builder in ADF.
Something like

`Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY default NEWID()`

Hope somebody can help me with this question.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it has this function named `uuid()`.It will return string value. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#uuid.

My test:

[image]

[image]